# check if column value changes for grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to check if a column value changes for each unique value of "Name".

The dataframe I have looks like this

| Name | Is finished? |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | No |
| Paul | No |
| Paul | No |
| John | No |
| John | No |
| John | Yes |
| John | Yes |
| Ringo | No |
| Ringo | No |
| Ringo | Yes |
| Ringo | Yes |
| Ringo | Yes |

My desired output is an extra column which either says "True" if a value has changed, and "False" if it didn't change. Desired output would look like this:

```
| Name | Is finished? | Change|
| -------- | -------------- |---|
| Paul    |      No|  False|
| Paul   | No|False|
| Paul    | No|False|
| John   | No|False|
| John    | No|False|
| John   | Yes|True|
| John| Yes|False|
| Ringo   | No|False|
| Ringo   | No|False|
| Ringo   | Yes|True|
| Ringo   | Yes|False|
| Ringo   | Yes|False|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `groupby` and `shift` to compare the current and previous row in `Is finished` column

```
c = 'Is finished?'
df['Change'] = df[c].eq('Yes') & df.groupby('Name')[c].shift().eq('No')
```

---

```
     Name Is finished?  Change
0    Paul           No   False
1    Paul           No   False
2    Paul           No   False
3    John           No   False
4    John           No   False
5    John          Yes    True
6    John          Yes   False
7   Ringo           No   False
8   Ringo           No   False
9   Ringo          Yes    True
10  Ringo          Yes   False
11  Ringo          Yes   False
```

Comment: Would this also work if someone starts with "Is finished?" value as "Yes", and then end with value "No"? This is also possible in my dataset.

Comment: In that case you could use `df.groupby('Name')[c].shift(fill_value='No').eq('No')` instead of `df.groupby('Name')[c].shift().eq('No')`